# In WCF we can aslo create REST-ful service using WebHttpBinding, so why we need Web API

Tags: rest, wcf

If we can create REST-ful service using WebHttpBinding in WCF, then why we need Web API.This question always strikes me can anyone help me in it. Do WCF REST-ful service have SOAP in it request or response?

Thanks.

Comment: `ASP.Net WebAPI` isn't a `REST` framework, instead it enables for creating `HTTP Services`. And yes we have `RESTFul WCF Services`, but  you know the implementations are brittle in terms of integrations between `RPC` & `HTTP`.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.net Web API is all about HTTP and REST based GET,POST,PUT,DELETE with well know ASP.net MVC style of programming and JSON returnable; web API is for all the light weight process and pure HTTP based components. For one to go ahead with WCF even for simple or simplest single web service it will bring all the extra baggage. For light weight simple service for ajax or dynamic calls always WebApi just solves the need. This neatly complements or helps in parallel to the ASP.net MVC.
here you can read more:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8a67c0/who-is-winner-web-api-or-wcf/